# Unable to create a directory on hdfs on mac os

Tags: macos, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

I am getting the below error message when I try to create a directory on hdfs.
I installed all the required softwares ssh, Java and set all the environment variables.
Not really sure where am I going wrong.

Could anyone share your thoughts on this? Thanks.

Command used:

```
bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir /Users/ravitejavutukuri/input
```

Error:

```
18/06/30 22:56:11 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
mkdir: `/Users/ravitejavutukuri/input': No such file or directory
```

Currently I installed Hadoop 2.9.1 and I'm trying to experiment with pseudo-distributed-mode.

Comment: Does `/Users/ravitejavutukuri` exist already?

Comment: You mean on hdfs?

Comment: Not sure why you accepted that answer. You now have a meaningless /Users folder in HDFS framework. If you just want an input directory, /tmp/input would be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command. It will create all the directories in the path.

```
bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /Users/ravitejavutukuri/input
```

Answer (score 1):

HDFS has no /Users directory (its not a Mac equivalent structure)

Did you mean `/user`?

The correct way to make a user directory for yourself would be

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /user/$whoami/
hdfs dfs -chmod -R 750 /user/$whoami/
```

Then to make an input directory, not giving an absolute path automatically uses your HDFS user folder

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir input/
```